# how to pass the entered value to a variable of another class after clicking the button? (java)

Tags: java, swing, awt

I made two classes in Java.Using GUI  
One is the main class and the other is the login class.
The login class is as follows.

```
loginTest.java
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.border.*;

public class loginTest 
{
    public static String Username=" ";
    public static String Password=" ";
    public loginTest()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel userlabel = new JLabel("user");
        userlabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25); // x y width height
        panel.add(userlabel);
        
        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);
        
        JLabel passwordlabel = new JLabel("password");
        passwordlabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordlabel);

        JTextField passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton button = new JButton("login");
        button.setBounds(140,80,80,25);
   
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Username = userText.getText();
                Password = passwordText.getText();
                SetName(Username);
                SetPW(Password);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        
        JLabel success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 100, 300,25);
        panel.add(success);     
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
    public void SetName(String Username)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
    }
    public void SetPW(String PassWord)
    {
        this.Password = PassWord;
    }
    public String GetName()
    {
        return Username;
    }
    public String GetPW()
    {
        return Password;
    }
}
```

and main_menu class:

```
main_menu.java
```

```
public class main_menu {
         public static String ID= " ";
         public static String PW= " ";
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         loginTest login_form = new loginTest(); 
         ID = login_form.GetName();
         PW = login_form.GetPW();
         System.out.println("user:" + ID+ "pw:" + PW);
         }
}
```

The result is nothing. NULL values appear or  user:null pw:null. 
how can i pass that name and password to main_menu class? 
I tried to hand over the value using set or get, but it didn't work.

Comment: You are going to give the user just a few nanoseconds to enter their name and password? (The execution time between `new loginTest` and `login_form.GetName();`)
Your naming makes the code v. difficult to read btw: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions

Comment: @g00se then should i use try and catch ? how long should i have to give it ? i

Comment: What did you change? - please tell us. Incidentally, you can get around this problem, and have a more rational arrangement by using a `CardLayout`: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout

Comment: @g00se i just use try and catch as u said are u give the user just a few nanoseconds,  Thread.sleep(10000); // for my slow hand and I'm not sure i will use CardLayout but i need something similar things like that as i want to switch frame after that frame.

Comment: Your LoginForm should be a modal JDialog. A modal dialog will block until the dialog is closed, which means the statements after the setVisible(...) statement will not execute in your main class until the dialog is closed.

Comment: Hehe, no don't do that! I wondered how on earth you solved it so quickly, Now I know you used a hammer instead of a screwdriver ;) You don't want to pause the main thread of your application and lock up the gui. I can't see how you're running the app. but I'm going to guess that's going to be quite weird. @camickr's way is better but not (IMO) as good as seeing the login screen as part of the whole application which must be passed to start

Comment: @camickr can u give me some example by answer this question?

Comment: @g00se as i'm not good at Java GUI i  don't know how to solved it properly. i mean something more efficient way , smart way. yeah it's quite weird to act but i don't have any other idea right now. if u don't mind can u give me some example?

Comment: @g00se and as u said it's hard to read the code, any suggestion for good coding naming style? thank u for read my code.

Comment: Yes. I gave you a link: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions